# Index OutOfRange Exception was unhandled in opencv circle detection

Tags: c#, emgucv

I am a newbie in computer vision, can anyone help me to solve the error? I have an error in for loop condition.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    double cannyThreshold = 180.0; 
    double circleAccumulatorThreshold = 120; 
    double cannyThresholdLinking = 160;
    Image<Bgr, Byte> imagez5 = capturez.QueryFrame().Resize(400, 400, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_LINEAR, true);
    pictureBox2.Image = imagez5.Bitmap;
    Image<Gray, Byte> gray = imagez5.Convert<Gray, Byte>().PyrDown().PyrUp();
    Image<Gray, byte> imagez7 = gray.Canny(cannyThreshold, cannyThresholdLinking);
    CircleF[] circlez = imagez7.HoughCircles(new Gray(cannyThreshold), new Gray(circleAccumulatorThreshold), 1, 60, 3, 300)[0];
    Image<Bgr, Byte> circleImage = imagez5.CopyBlank();

    for (int i =0; i<=circlez.Length; i++)
    {
        imagez7.Draw(circlez[i], new Gray(255), 3);
    }
    pictureBox1.Image = imagez7.Bitmap;
}
```

Comment: It should be  for (int i =0; i<circlez.Length; i++) and check if no of detected circles is zero

Comment: yeah i tried it out... but it doesn't enter into for loop to draw.

Comment: check if imagez7.HoughCircles doesn't return null before getting channel at index 0

Comment: HoughCircles() failed to detect any circle for the parameters you have given. (I tried with default webcam though)

Answer (score 0):

remove equality from the loop

```
for (int i =0; i<circlez.Length; i++)
{
    imagez7.Draw(circlez[i], new Gray(255), 3);

}
```

make sure that

```
imagez7.HoughCircles(
    new Gray(cannyThreshold), new Gray(circleAccumulatorThreshold), 1, 60, 3, 300)
```

does not return null

Comment: make sure that circlez.Length > 0

Comment: it doesn't throw OutOfRange exception if length is 0

Comment: yea..but in that code he is checking i<=circlez.Length which throws outofrange when length is zero

Comment: yea if length is zero means its throws outofrange exception... my problem is its doesn't enter into for loop

Comment: After for (int i =0; i<circlez.Length; i++) it won't raise that exception, as for the problem, have you checked if imagez7.HoughCircles(...) is not null before getting the first index element imagez7.HoughCircles(...)[0]

Comment: or this http://leakingmemory.wordpress.com/2012/03/17/shape-recognition-using-c-and-aforge/